# aframe: how does look-controls set its initial values

Tags: aframe

When an AFrame `<scene>` gets loaded and a `camera` component has been set with `look-controls` enabled, how does the current orientation of the device (mobile) set the values of rotation and position of the camera?

Since a scene will have a certain point of origin. I have found that when open the scene from different positions the initial view is different, while I would like it to be the "look ahead" view.

The code is simple:

`<a-entity camera="userHeight:1.6" look-controls></a-entity>`

Comment: Here is my observation. I load the url containing the scene is an `<iframe>`. Which ever direction I am facing, the origin is ahead of me (because the camera is set behind a few metres). That is as expected. Now, if I change my orientation (say turn left) and dynamically (via javascript) load a `<a-scene>`, it keeps the original position of the origin and shows the new scene as though the camera has moved to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`look-controls` takes the orientation from the sensors of the phone that is absolute and not relative to where you position the camera initially in the scene. The initial values are overridden by those coming from the sensors. Phones in 2017 do not have positional tracking but have a head neck model and calculate the position of your eyes with respect of the base of your neck which is the rotation pivot.

I don't know the context of your application but in VR you cannot rely on the same degree of control of the camera that you would have on a traditional 3D application. If you require the user to look in a certain direction you can place hints or indications to influence the user's behavior.

Comment: In any VR app, the user is in some direction in the absolute world and when a scene is opened the user should see the front as determined by the app. That happens. However, when the scene is closed and a new scene is opened (within the same app) and if the user has changed direction (say moved to the right by 45 deg), the new scene will not show up in front and neither does the camera show that it is off the orientation of the scene.

Comment: However, if after change in direction the app is reloaded the scene appears in front. Hence I wanted to know if there is a way to re-orient the scene to match the direction of the mobile when it gets loaded. (not sure if I am clear on this)

Comment: The app is a classroom VR app where movement of the user is strictly done via script but rotational movements are permitted to give a sense of looking around and talking to neighbours.

Comment: You can rotate the whole scene by creating a parent entity that contains the classroom.