# Programmatically change webvr camera view

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I want to programmatically move the position of the view in a webvr scene. To do this I am using the position.add method.

Here is how I move the camera programmatically:

```
 <a-entity position="33 0 -33" rotation="0 180 0" look-controls id="camera" 
       camera="userHeight: 1.6" listener></a-entity>
```

Camerage is moved here:

```
 var obj3d = document.querySelector("#camera").object3D;
 var angleobj = obj3d.getWorldDirection();
 angleobj.y = 0;
 obj3d.position.add(angleobj.multiplyScalar(0.004*3));
```

This works in normal mode, but in cardboard mode, the camera is not moving. How can I move the camera in cardboard view mode programmatically?

Comment: Rotate a wrapper entity versus the camera directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, once you switch to the "VR mode", you get to use other camera than the one outside of "VR mode".

I think You should listen for the VR enter / exit events, and change the camera reference:

```
this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('enter-vr',() => {
     obj3d = document.querySelector("#camera").object3D;
}
this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('exit-vr',() => {
     obj3d = document.querySelector("#camera").object3D;
}
```

---

Please rethink, if this is necessary, when the user moves his head, and the camera goes wild, it can get really dizzy, really fast.

A-frame's Diego Marcos in his [anwsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667475/aframe-how-does-look-controls-set-its-initial-values/47667912#47667912) often recommends visual indications WHERE to look, instead of such options.

---

If the above does not work, try grabbing the camera entity, instead if its object3D:

```
var obj3d = document.querySelector("#camera");
```

and move it using the setAttribute() method

```
obj3d.setAttribute("position", {x: _x, y: _y, z: _z});
```

Comment: i implemented your suggestion. the enter/exit-vr events are detected but it still doesn't work in the full view. any ideas how to make this work?